# Inverse of a Toeplitz matrix with FFT-based methods

Tags: matrices, fourier-analysis, inverse, fast-fourier-transform, toeplitz-matrices

I have a covariance matrix $Q$ and need to find $Q^{-1}$. Here, $Q$ is a Toeplitz matrix. I want to calculate the inverse of the matrix with FFT-based methods rather than the conventional ones like the Cholesky, QR or eigenvalue decompositions, or other Toeplitz inversion methods like Levinson-Trench or Berlekamp-Massey.

Can anyone tell me how can I do that please? Is there any established method which I can follow?

Comment: Do you know the relationship between the DFT matrix and circulant matrices?

Comment: Maybe the eigen values of a circulant matrix is the DFT of its first column? Am I right?

Comment: Right, and its eigenvectors form the DFT matrix itself. Therefore, if you have a circulant matrix, $C$, and you want to solve a system, $Cx=b$, you can simply write, $FDF^Hx = b \rightarrow DF^Hx = F^Hb$. Now count the fft's. We need one to determine the diagonal matrix $D$ (as you stated in your comment), another to determine $F^Hb$, and finally one inverse fft to recover $x$ from $F^Hx$.

Comment: Now, as for Toeplitz matrices, there is a trick to embed it into a larger matrix as to make it circulant. I'll refer you to this: http://web.eecs.utk.edu/~dongarra/etemplates/node384.html

Comment: @Chester I don't think it can be used for matrix inversion? Only for multiplication